# how do you deploy a jar file using the weblogic.deployer?

Tags: java, deployment, jar, weblogic

I am looking on automating weblogic jar deployments using the weblogic deployer.

I am looking for good examples really.

I have see this so far :-

```
java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:10001 -user <user> -password <password> -name mylib -library -libspecver 1.0 -libimplver 2.0 -deploy c:/myapps/mylib.jar
```

what is `-libspecver` and `libimplver` ?

What will the deployed jar look like on the weblogic console gui - display name and version ?

Thank You
(a non java developer)

Comment: libspecver indicates Library Spec Version and libimplver indicates Library Implementation Version. Based on the name it looks like a library and in console you can see them under Deployments as Type Library.

Comment: Thx ,I'll check that out. I have gotten these versions from the manifest file. With these values, which must match what's in the manifest. I used them on the weblogic.deployer .library jar file deployment command. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article about [deploying](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13702/deploy.htm#DEPGD251).

It is best practice to include version string information for a library for the deployment, but its only recommendation.

```
If you are deploying a library or package that does not include version string information, you can specify it at the command line using one or both of the following options:

    libspecver—Defines a specification version for the library or package.

    libimplver—Specifies an implementation version for the library or package.
```